# BL460c G7 blade OS install

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server

I have an HP c7000 enclosure with a BL460c G7 blade. I need to install Windows server OS on it. I have a problem with iLO, so it will not mount the ISO in the remote console. Tried using both Active-X and the Java console. In the Active-X console i get a timeout mounting the ISO and in Java i get "network error (java.net.socketexception socket closed)".

Anyway the real question now, while waiting for the network guys: Is there any other way to install an OS on a BL460c G7 than mounting an ISO in iLO remote console? Can i connect a DVD ROM to a USB port or anything. Is there any way i can possibly get to read the install DVD so i can get the OS installed on the blade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are certain ports needed in order to gain ILO and remote media access to an HP ProLiant system. The G7 systems use ILO3, so the general port cheat-sheet is:

```
====================
List Forwarded iLO Ports
====================
22 Secure Shell (SSH)
23 Remote Console / telnet
80 Web Server Non-SSL (HTTP)
443 Web Server SSL (HTTPS)
3389 Terminal Services
17988 Virtual Media
9300 Shared Remote Console
17990 Console Replay
3002 Raw Serial Data
====================
```

In short, 23, 80, 443 and 17988 are the main ports you'll need access to in order to perform an installation through the GUI. Are you being blocked by a firewall? Do you have any way to get directly onto the ILO's network (assuming it's on a different network segment). I often end up using a convoluted SSH forwarding string to accomplish this at distant sites...

```
ssh -L 22:<iLO ip address>:22 -L 23:<iLO ip address>:23 -L 80:<iLO ip address>:80 -L 443:<iLO ip address>:443 -L 3389:<iLO ip address>:3389
-L 17988:<iLO ip address>:17988 -L 9300:<iLO ip address>:9300 -L 17990:<iLO ip address>:17990 -L 3002:<iLO ip address>:3002 user@gateway
```

There are other options, though. You can SSH to the ILO and force it to mount a .ISO file residing at a URL. From the ILO ssh interface:
 
`vm cdrom insert http://192.168.1.100/path/to/Windows.iso` 
followed by
 `vm cdrom set boot_once` will tell the ILO to source the .ISO from a specific location.

There's also a USB/KVM dongle that can be attached directly to the blade server. On is included with each enclosure. That would allow the use of a USB DVD drive, assuming someone has physical access to the server.

[image]